# Convert text to raw format

Tags: text

How to convert a text to raw format without any special chars. This is because some tools formats the text. Lets say I am copying a query from outook to sql developer or hive, the query doesn't execute.
How to remove all formating and run it as plain text.

Comment: Depends on your tools, environment etc. Not related to the SQL _language_ though.

Comment: Paste it in notepad in between which will strip any formatting. And see if you can set your Outlook to just RTF/Rich Text which can help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

```
1. Copy the query from outook
2. Paste the query in notepad
3. Copy the query again from notepad
4. Past the query in sql developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to address this, depending on the situation -
What goes in the clipboard by default depends on the browser/tools. Text processors like Microsoft Word usually have options to ignore pasted style, so it shouldn't be an issue if you want to learn how to use it properly.

Following are few ways -

a) Copy the text and paste to any other text editor. I use "notes" on Mac or MS Word or sublime sometimes. Once pasted, copy that pasted text and use them as raw text which will remove all your formatting.

b) You can also use this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-as-plain-text/eneajgkmdhmjmloiabgkpkiooaejmlpk?hl=en which will allow you to right click on selected part and copy it as a raw text.

c) Sometimes - Ctrl + alt + v or ctrl +shift + v should paste what's on your clipboard as unformatted text. Very handy for copying code samples to word docs. This should also work on Mac if you substitute cmd for Ctrl.